# LiveCode Revert From Standalone Application back to source file (.livecode)

Tags: windows, macos, livecode

In livecode, after I've exported a standalone application, is there a way to revert the executable file back into it's original source file?  i.e. turn the .app or .exe back into an editable .livecode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the standalone is built, it can't be separated into its component parts again.  It used to be possible but that has long since been changed.

Comment: If the files were exported a long time ago would it be possible somehow?  Or is it an issue with the livecode IDE itself?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it isn't an 'issue with the LiveCode IDE', more a change in the way standalone apps are built now, they used to build with a separate Runtime Engine that would open the stacks, but this method was changed when the engine and stacks were combined to build a standalone app.

However, there is a scenario where stacks can still be opened from a standalone app.
If you build your app using the "**Splash Stack**" method, i.e. Have one splash stack to open sub-stacks and check the "**Move substacks into individual stack files**", or use separate stacks added in the "**Standalone Application Settings > Copy Files**" option, then these stacks or substacks are available to open in the Mac OS app package or in the Windows Program folder of the standalone.

To protect stacks in this scenario you can use the "**Encrypt with password**" option available in the commercial version of LC.

Comment: The Scenario is this:  The Application is already built, but the source code is bad.  I need to revert the standalone app back into source files.  Not re-build.  Perhaps I'm just mis-understanding your answer, but I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: Unfortunately here is no way to reverse engineer a standalone to its stack file after it has been built. As Jacque mentioned, this used to be possible in previous revision of LiveCode but this posed huge stack security implications so it was quickly resolved